# Why is my camera app crashing?

Tags: android, camera, release

API 15. When I stop my camera after taking a picture and go to the home screen and reopen my app and try to take another picture, my app crashes and I get this error:

```
04-20 12:04:38.437: E/AndroidRuntime(5150): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-2
04-20 12:04:38.437: E/AndroidRuntime(5150): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
04-20 12:04:38.437: E/AndroidRuntime(5150):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
04-20 12:04:38.437: E/AndroidRuntime(5150):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:947)
04-20 12:04:38.437: E/AndroidRuntime(5150):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:892)
04-20 12:04:38.437: E/AndroidRuntime(5150):     at com.prism.app.PrismActivity$5.run(PrismActivity.java:167)
04-20 12:04:38.437: E/AndroidRuntime(5150):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)


public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    if (mCamera == null) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // error setting preview of camera
        }
    } else {
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release(); //need to take care of case when app is not closed completely still need to release
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code to your run method which is where the crash seems to be happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace, it looks like you have some `TimerTask` that is still scheduled to execute which uses the camera. It triggers after you close the camera, thus the error. You need `cancel()` the `Timer`, and also be prepared for the fact that the last `TimerTask` may be in progress from before you cancel. So the task needs to check whether the camera is closed before it operates on it.

Comment: I cancel my TimerTask before I close the app. The preview still shows up after I reopen, but I get a force close when I try to take another picture. (This is sort of a timelapse app).

Comment: (@AustynMahoney: I did not downvote anything. Your statement is correct, though I think the OP's question is why it is this is happening.)

Comment: @hotnspicyxp: Then you are likely holding on to an old reference to a `Camera`. You should probably start/stop the camera in `onResume()` and `onPause()` not these methods as I don't think they get called when you think.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what was happening.

Answer (score -1):

Essentially you are trying to use your `mCamera` object after it's release method has been called and the OS has released it in it's native code.

The object still exists (so your `mCamera == null` evaluates to `false`), but the object can no longer be used without creating a new one or calling a method that grabs the native resources again.